# How can i parse nested xml using GDataXML parser?

Tags: iphone, ios, xml, xml-parsing, gdataxml

How can I get this `<firstName>` and `<lastName>`. I have tried a lot but I have messed up.

```
<list>
<OrderData HASH="1843180441">
 <id>26</id><customer>
  <CustomerData HASH="882063912"> 
   <id>1</id> 
   <sex>Male</sex>
   <firstName>admin</firstName>
   <lastName>admin</lastName>
   <companyName>Individual</companyName>
   <userName>admin</userName>
   <password>21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3</password>    
   <lastLogin>2012-01-26T12:11:38</lastLogin>
   <status>A</status>
   <created>2011-09-28T07:01:47</created>
   <modified>2012-01-26T12:11:38</modified>
   <canChangePassword>Y</canChangePassword>
   <isDeleted>false</isDeleted>
   <abn/>
   <abnBranch/>
 <storeCredit>50000.0</storeCredit>
 <billingAddress>
 <list>
 <AddressData HASH="768553743">
  <id>2</id>
  <firstName>admin</firstName>
  <lastName>admin</lastName>
  <addressLine1>suite: 1307, 9 Yara Street</addressLine1> 
  <addressLine2>dgdgdf</addressLine2>
  <postCode>3000</postCode>
  <suburb>dfgdfg</suburb>
  <city>sadf</city>
  <phone>4456</phone>
  <mobile/>
  <fax/>
  <active>true</active>
  <type>C</type>
  <email>afzal.bitmascot@gmail.com</email>
  <log/>
 </AddressData>
 </deliveryAddress>
 <purchaseDate>2011-10-03T03:23:48</purchaseDate>

</OrderData>
<OrderData HASH="1569451006"></OrderData>
<OrderData HASH="1449383081"></OrderData>
<OrderData HASH="1438157618"></OrderData>
<OrderData HASH="269308788"></OrderData>
</list>
```

Till now I have done this.

```objective-c
 NSLog(@"Enering in the xml file");
 NSArray *getNumberOfOrder = [[xmlDocument rootElement] elementsForName:@"OrderData"];

 for(GDataXMLElement *e in getNumberOfOrder){
   for(int i =0;i<[[e elementsForName:@"customer"]count];i++){
        // All orderd customer name
        NSString  *orderByFirstString = [[[[e elementsForName:@"customer"] objectAtIndex:0] childAtIndex:2] stringValue];
        NSString  *orderByLastString = [[[[e elementsForName:@"customer"] objectAtIndex:0] childAtIndex:3]stringValue];
        orderByString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",orderByFirstString,orderByLastString];
        NSLog(@"order By String: %@",orderByString);
        }
 }
```

Cordially appreciate for any help or suggestion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I parse this xml using GDataXML parser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156302/how-can-i-parse-this-xml-using-gdataxml-parser)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try something like this.  I would loop through the XML document, and store it in an array.

Notice the NSLog() which will print to the console and will help you see what is going on.

```
xmlDocument = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc]initWithData:xmlData options:0 error:nil];

NSArray *temp = [xmlDocument.rootElement elementsForName:@"OrderData"];

for(GDataXMLElement *e in temp) {
    [outputArray addObject:e];
    NSLog(@"%@", e);
}
```

Then I would loop through the array, and do something like this when I wanted to retrieve a result such as the customer's first name.

```
for (int i = 0; i < [outputArray count]; i++) {
   NSString *firstName = [[[[[[[[outputArray objectAtIndex:i]elementsForName:@"customer"] objectAtIndex:0] elementsForName:@"CustomerData"] objectAtIndex:0] childAtIndex:2]stringValue];
}
```

Comment: If you post a full section of the XML document, that would help

Comment: What is the NSLog statement printing?  If Nothing, then you doing something wrong before parsing the file

Comment: It would also be nice to see more of the XML files, and i'm sure we can get it to work

Comment: Okay I get errors when I try to parse the file.  For one check out  </deliveryAddress> there is no <deliveryAddress>, that is not a proper XML structure.  You also need to see what your NSLog prints out in that for loop, if nothing prints out then you have an error before parsing.  It's hard to help you when I don't know the XML file structure or what errors you are getting.

Comment: Check out this tutorial, maybe that will help you out - http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml

Comment: i have seen that tutorial but i did not get any help or may be i did not understand their solution.So if you help me then it will so glad to you

Comment: i did not allocate the `outputArray`,that's why it did not work.Now it is working...