# How can I parse this xml using GDataXML parser?

Tags: iphone, ios, xml, xml-parsing, gdataxml

```
<list>
    <OrderData HASH="1408108039"></OrderData>
    <OrderData HASH="208524692">
        <id>97</id>
        <customer>
            <CustomerData HASH="2128670187"></CustomerData></customer>
        <billingAddress></billingAddress><deliveryAddress></deliveryAddress>
        <orderDetail>
            <list>
                <OrderDetailData HASH="516790072"></OrderDetailData>
                <OrderDetailData HASH="11226247"></OrderDetailData>
                <OrderDetailData HASH="11226247"></OrderDetailData>
            </list>
        </orderDetail>
        <log/>
    </OrderData>
    <OrderData HASH="1502226778"></OrderData>
</list>
```

I cannot find a solution to find the number of `OrderDetailData` elements? I also read http://iphonebyradix.blogspot.com/2011/03/using-gdata-to-parse-xml-file.html this url.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

I am explaining my requirement again. In this xml there will be multiple `OrderData` element. Now I have to count the number of `OrderDetailData` elemnts from a particular `OrderData` element. Suppose that, according to my xml, the current parsed xml has one `OrderData` element, named `id` and its value is 97. Now, I have to count how many `OrderDetailData` elements are contained in the OrderData`(which`id` is 97).

Comment: why ur not using NSXMlParser??

Comment: Because i have to edit this xml.that's mean i have to rewrite the xml.

Comment: try this tutorial :-http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml

Comment: i also read it..but i am not finding solution.

Comment: I have edited my question,please now help me anybody.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a simple example how to retrieve some data. This example is very simple and not use XPath expression. I suggest you first understand how it works and then use XPath expression. In my opinion it is not useful to use XPath expression if you cannot understand how the parser works.

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test2" ofType:@"xml"];

NSData *xmlData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSError *error;
GDataXMLDocument *doc = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:xmlData 
                                                       options:0 error:&error];
//NSLog(@"%@", doc.rootElement); // print the whole xml

NSArray *orderDataArray = [doc.rootElement elementsForName:@"OrderData"];

for (GDataXMLElement *orderDataElement in orderDataArray) {

    if([orderDataElement childCount] > 0)
    {            
        NSString *attributeForOrderDataElement = [(GDataXMLElement *) [orderDataElement attributeForName:@"HASH"] stringValue];   

        NSLog(@"attributeForOrderDataElement has value %@", attributeForOrderDataElement);

        GDataXMLElement* idElement = (GDataXMLElement*)[[orderDataElement elementsForName:@"id"] objectAtIndex:0];

        NSLog(@"id has value %@", idElement.stringValue);

        GDataXMLElement* orderDetailElement = (GDataXMLElement*)[[orderDataElement elementsForName:@"orderDetail"] objectAtIndex:0];

        GDataXMLElement* listElement = (GDataXMLElement*)[[orderDetailElement elementsForName:@"list"] objectAtIndex:0];            

        NSArray* orderDetailDataArray = [listElement elementsForName:@"OrderDetailData"];

        int count = 0;
        for (GDataXMLElement *orderDetailDataElement in orderDetailDataArray) {

            NSString *attributeForOrderDetailDataElement = [(GDataXMLElement *) [orderDetailDataElement attributeForName:@"HASH"] stringValue];

            NSLog(@"attributeForOrderDetailDataElement has value %@", attributeForOrderDetailDataElement);

            count++;
        }

        NSLog(@"%d", count);
    }
}

[doc release];
[xmlData release];
```

This is the output console:

```
attributeForOrderDataElement has value 208524692 <-- HASH value
id has value 97 <-- id value
attributeForOrderDetailDataElement has value 516790072 <-- HASH value
attributeForOrderDetailDataElement has value 11226247
attributeForOrderDetailDataElement has value 11226247
3 <-- the count
```

Hope it helps.

**Edit**

test2.xml contains your file but you could pass it as a string. You can also pass as parameters as string like the following:

```
NSString* xmlString = @"<list>"
    "<OrderData HASH=\"1408108039\"></OrderData>"
    "<OrderData HASH=\"208524692\">"
    "<id>97</id>"
    "<customer>"
    "<CustomerData HASH=\"2128670187\"></CustomerData>"
    "</customer>"
    "<billingAddress></billingAddress>"
    "<deliveryAddress></deliveryAddress>"
    "<orderDetail>"
    "<list>"
    "<OrderDetailData HASH=\"516790072\"></OrderDetailData>"
    "<OrderDetailData HASH=\"11226247\"></OrderDetailData>"
    "<OrderDetailData HASH=\"11226247\"></OrderDetailData>"
    "</list>"
    "</orderDetail>"
    "<log/>"
    "</OrderData>"
    "<OrderData HASH=\"1502226778\"></OrderData>"
    "</list>";    

GDataXMLDocument *doc = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc] initWithXMLString:xmlString options:0 error:&error];
```

Comment: You are so so much helpful.Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you. With any other language xml is simple to load and parse. But with Cocoa and Objective C, what a nightmare.  +1

Answer (score 1):

I found TouchXML easy in parsing and you can directly access data needed from xml

First of all Download TouchXML and add libxml2.dylib framework to your project.
change buildsetting for "Header Search Path" and add "/usr/include/libxml2"
Import TouchXML.h to your file

```
//Access document 
CXMLDocument *parserDoc = [[CXMLDocument alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url options:0 error:&err];

//Access root element and access children in heirarchy
CXMLElement *root = [parserDoc rootElement];
NSArray *places = [[[root children] objectAtIndex:0] children];
```

**Else**

```
//Access node by node
NSString *location =[[[[[parserDoc nodesForXPath:@"/xml_api_reply/weather/forecast_information/city" error:nil] objectAtIndex:0] attributeForName:@"data"] stringValue] retain];
```

Answer (score 0):

If the OrderDetailData is present in 2nd object of array all the time, u can use the below

```
NSArray* arr = [[XMLelement elementForName:@"list"] elementsForName:@"OrderData"];    
NSXMLElement* listElement = [[[arr objectAtIndex:1] elementForName:@"orderDetail"] elementForName:@"list"];
NSArray* orderDetailArray* = [listElement elementsForName:@"OrderDetailData"];
```

In this u can get the OrderDetailData elements in the array, and u can parse the data in loop. to get HASH value use.

```
NSString* hash = [[orderDetailArray objectAtIndex:0] stringValueForAttribute:@"HASH"];
```

Comment: Please read the question carefully.I want to use GdataXml parser to parse these data.

Comment: yes, this is by using GDataXML parser only, just class names are different, instead of NSXMLElement u can use GDataXMLElement

Comment: `NSArray* arr = [[XMLelement elementForName:@"list"] elementsForName:@"OrderData"];` when i use `GDataXMLElement` is stead of `XMLelement` then i got this warning `class method "+elementForName" not found`

Comment: u use NSXMLElement only, i have check library u have given.. here XMLElement is the root element of ur xml string

Comment: wthr d issue is not yet fixed...?

Comment: not yet please can you write full code....may be it will painful for you.but please help me..

Answer (score 0):

This is the below code, i have tried. I got the right output.. check out

```
NSString* xmlString = @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"
                       "<list>"
                       "<OrderData HASH=\"1408108039\"></OrderData>"
                       "<OrderData HASH=\"208524692\">"
                       "<id>97</id>"
                       "<customer>"
                       "<CustomerData HASH=\"2128670187\"></CustomerData></customer>"
                       "<billingAddress></billingAddress><deliveryAddress></deliveryAddress>"
                       "<orderDetail>"
                       "<list>"
                       "<OrderDetailData HASH=\"516790072\"></OrderDetailData>"
                       "<OrderDetailData HASH=\"11226247\"></OrderDetailData>"
                       "<OrderDetailData HASH=\"11226247\"></OrderDetailData>"
                       "</list>"
                       "</orderDetail>"
                       "<log/></OrderData>"
                       "<OrderData HASH=\"1502226778\"></OrderData>"
                       "</list>";

NSXMLDocument*  doc = [[NSXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:[xmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:nil];
NSXMLElement* rootElement = [doc rootElement];

NSArray* arr = [rootElement elementsForName:@"OrderData"];
NSXMLElement* orderDataElement;

for (int i = 0; i < [arr count]; i++)
{
    int Id = 0;
    Id = [[arr objectAtIndex:i] integerValueForNode:@"id"];
    if (Id != 0)
    {
        orderDataElement = [arr objectAtIndex:i];
        break;
    }
}

NSArray* orderDetailArray = [[[orderDataElement elementForName:@"orderDetail"] 
                              elementForName:@"list"] 
                             elementsForName:@"OrderDetailData"];

for (int j = 0; j < [orderDetailArray count]; j++)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [[orderDetailArray objectAtIndex:j] stringValueForAttribute:@"HASH"]);
}
```